# update query question

Tags: sql, oracle11g

i have this table MEN

```
Fname
aaa
bbb
ccc
aaa
aaa
bbb
ggg
```

i need query that replace all the aaa - in - ZZZ

```
Fname
ZZZ
bbb
ccc
ZZZ
ZZZ
bbb
ggg
```

how to do it on Oracle query ?

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "replace all the aaa - in - ZZZ"? Is `aaa` just a substring (e.g. `xxaaaxx`) or is it the complete string to change?

Comment: good thought by alex R 

but didn't get any comments on this by Gali .!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will work not only in Oracle

```
update MEN
set Fname='ZZZ'
where Fname='aaa';
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE MEN SET Fname='ZZZ' WHERE Fname='aaa';

see http://psoug.org/reference/update.html